# Remainder operator java when dividing 1 by x

Tags: java, math, modulus

I have read at the stackoverflow this:

Modulus 50 % 100

Think of it in this way:

100 goes into 50 how many times?

Zero times. So there must be 50 left over. Therefore, the answer is 50.

This was the easiest way to understand/calculate modulus for me. However, when I take the same approach for 1 % 3 a problem appears. 3 goes into 1 how many times? Zero, so there must be 3 left over? No actually it is 1, but why? It's also a case for 2 % 11 and probably many others, what this is about?

Comment: For `x % y`, where `x` is smaller than `y`, what is left over is the value of `x`. So for `1 % 3`, left over is 1. For `2 % 11`, left over is 2. And so on ...

Comment: @Antonh always? e.g. 34 & 100 = 34, 11 % 44 = 11 ??

Comment: Modulus is just the remainder from dividing both x and y.

Comment: @Antonh It seems to work when checked in calculator

Comment: @robinhood Yes. I just simplified the definition of a division to the part you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 goes into 1 zero times with **1** left over. Not 3.

**NOTE** There is no modulus operator in Java. It is specified as a remainder operator. This affects the meaning and the value of the result in several cases.

Answer (score 2):

The division algorithm:

`r` is defined to be `a % b`.

"If a and b are positive integers, there exist unique integers q, r with
a = b*q + r and 0 ≤ r < b."

1 = 3*0 + 1, so the answer is 1.

(0 ≤ 1 < 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `a % b` as the remainder of `a / b` or

```
a % b = a - a / b * b;

1 % 3 = 1 - 1 / 3 * 3;
      = 1 - 0 * 3
      = 1
```

It get more interesting when you have -4 % 3

```
-4 % 3 = -4 - -4 / 3 * 3
       = -4 - -3
       = -1
```